# Taxonomy term description gets emptied on term save

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary with a description field that's of the "Long text and summary" type.
Every time I edit and save a taxonomy term from that vocabulary, the description gets emptied.

Did any of you encounter this bug?
Is there any way of fixing it?

Comment: I have just experienced this issue. I just updated to Drupal 7.36, but not sure if the issue was active before I updated. What version are you running?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.34. I have even opened an issue: [https://www.drupal.org/node/2451589], but no answer yet. So, **I just created a new "Long text and summary" field and hid the default description field and it worked**, because the problem only occurs when using the default description field that's converted to a "Long text and summary" field.